# Searching an object array for certain values

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

Hey everyone so I am stuck on the last part of this program that I have been doing for an assignment. So generally I am given a large list of names and numbers that represent popularity ranks for names in certain decades. [This is what the file looks like](http://www.writeurl.com/text/ew40igzvms0lvavaf6h1/7mwg41itnrkgyqy37gy8/lbda0mglln5bjue1pdzr) <----- this is a link to see the names.txt

So I created a method that sorts the list in a certain decade which is the getIndexOfSmallest and interchange. Every decade has two names that are ranked the same so between the years of 1900-1909 there are two names that are ranked 1, two names that are ranked 2, two names that are ranked 3 and so on. The last part of the program and the one I need help with is suppose to sort through the object array and find any decades where there is only one name for one rank or no names for a certain rank. The output will be sent to a file and [it will look like this.](http://www.writeurl.com/text/x0sh40c9xeeljnj9inhy/lefopzgowijt25fxl2fj/zwr69tw51eue614wmxkf) <------ this is another link to see the expected output

This is what my code looks like. This is my Name code that creates the objects:

```
public class Name{

private String givenName;
private int[] ranks = new int[12];

public Name(String name, int[] popularityRanks){
    givenName = name;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        ranks[i] = popularityRanks[i];
    }
}

public String getName(){
    return givenName;
}

public int getPop(int decade){
    if (decade >= 0 && decade <= 10){
        return ranks[decade];
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

public String getHistoLine(int decade){     
    String histoLine = ranks[decade] + ": ";
    double popularity = (1000 - ranks[decade]) / 11.7;
    int histo = (int)popularity;

    if(popularity != 0){

        for (int i = 0; i < histo; i++){
            histoLine += "*";
        }
    }

    return histoLine;
}

public String getHistogram(){
    String histogram = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        histogram += this.getHistoLine(i) + "\n";
    }

    return histogram;
}
}
```

This is my NameApp which is where my main is at:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NameApp{

private static boolean validInput;
private static boolean stillWorking = true;
private static boolean validDecade;
private static boolean validName;

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

// Main method
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[] nameArray = readNamesFile();
    Name[] list = new Name[nameArray.length];

    loadNames(list, nameArray);

    char choice;

    do {

        do {

            displayMenu();
            choice = getUserInput();

        } while (!validInput);

        switch (choice){
            case 'A':
                    displayHistogram(list);
                break;
            case 'B':
                    compareTwoNames(list);
                break;
            case 'C':
                    displayTopTenNames(list);
                break;
            case 'D':
                    writeAnomaliesToFile(list);
                    stillWorking = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    } while (stillWorking);
}   

/*
 * This method will read the file name names.txt and load the names and populations into a string array.
 */
private static String[] readNamesFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[] nameArray = new String[4429];

    Scanner inputStream = null;
    String fileName = "names.txt";
    inputStream = new Scanner (new File(fileName));

    int i = 0;

    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        nameArray[i] = inputStream.nextLine();

        i++;
    }

    inputStream.close();
    return nameArray;
}

/*
 * load names method will take a Name array and the string array from the readNamesFile method. This method will split the names and the population ranks and send them to the constructor in Name.java.
 */
private static void loadNames(Name[] list, String[] nameArray){
    int length;
    int spacePos;
    int[] popRanks = new int[11];
    String name;
    String linePop;

    for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++){
        length = nameArray[i].length();

        spacePos = nameArray[i].indexOf(" ");

        name = nameArray[i].substring(0,spacePos);
        linePop = nameArray[i].substring(spacePos + 1, length);

        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
            popRanks[j] = Integer.parseInt(linePop.split(" ")[j]);
        }

        list[i] = new Name(name, popRanks);
    }
}

/*
 * displayMenu method will display the menu that the user will select their program function.
 */
private static void displayMenu(){
    System.out.println("Enter the character corresponding to your selection:");
    System.out.println("\ta - Print histogram for a name");
    System.out.println("\tb - Compare two names in a decade");
    System.out.println("\tc - Print top ten names for a decade");
    System.out.println("\td - Quit (display file anomalies)");
}

/*
 * getUserInput is a method that will accept a string input from the user it will send this string to two different helper methods.
 */
private static char getUserInput(){

    String selection = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("   Your selection: " + selection);

    checkUserInput(selection);

    char choice = stringToChar(selection);

    return choice;
}

/*
 * helper method: checkUserInput will accept the user input from getUserInput and test the input to see if the input is a valid input from the user. If it is not set the instance boolean variable to false if it is set it to true.
 */
private static boolean checkUserInput(String selection){

    if (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("a") && !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("b") && !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("c") && !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again...");
        return validInput = false;
    }
    else {          
        return validInput = true;
    }

}

/*
 * helper method: stringToChar method will take the input that the user entered after it has been tested to see if it is valid and this method will change the input to a character value. This will also make the character to an upper case letter.
 */
private static char stringToChar(String selection){
    char choice = selection.charAt(0);

    choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);

    return choice;
}

/*
 * Menu option: A. This method will take a user input for the name they want and display the histogram for the selected name.
 */
private static void displayHistogram(Name[] list){
    String nameInput;
    String histogram;
    int nameLocation;

    do {
        nameInput = nameEntry();

        nameLocation = checkListArray(nameInput, list);

        if (!validName){
            System.out.println("The name, " + nameInput + ", was not found!");
        }

    } while (!validName);

    histogram = list[nameLocation].getHistogram();

    System.out.println("Histogram for name, " + list[nameLocation].getName() + ":");
    System.out.println(histogram);
}

private static void compareTwoNames(Name[] list){
    String nameOne;
    String nameTwo;
    String oneHistoLine;
    String twoHistoLine;
    int oneLocation;
    int twoLocation;
    int decade;

    do {
        nameOne = nameEntry();
        oneLocation = checkListArray(nameOne, list);

        if (!validName){
            System.out.println("The first name, " + nameOne + ", was not found!");
        }

    } while (!validName);

    do {
        nameTwo = nameEntry();
        twoLocation = checkListArray(nameTwo, list);

        if (!validName){
            System.out.println("The second name, " + nameTwo + ", was not found!");
        }

    } while(!validName);


    decadeMenu();
    decade = decadeSelection();

    oneHistoLine = list[oneLocation].getHistoLine(decade);
    twoHistoLine = list[twoLocation].getHistoLine(decade);

    System.out.println("Data for " + list[oneLocation].getName());
    System.out.println(" " + oneHistoLine);
    System.out.println("Data for " + list[twoLocation].getName());
    System.out.println(" " + twoHistoLine);
}

private static void displayTopTenNames(Name[] list){
    int decade;
    int count = 0;
    int l = 0;
    String[] decadeName = new String[20];
    Name[] temp = new Name[list.length];

    decadeMenu();
    decade = decadeSelection();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        temp[i] = list[i];
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < temp.length; index++){
        int smallestIndex = getIndexOfSmallest(decade, index, temp);
        interchange(decade, index, smallestIndex, temp);
    }

    do {

        if (temp[l].getPop(decade) == 0){
            l++;
        } 
        else {
            decadeName[count] = temp[l].getName() + " " + "(" + temp[l].getPop(decade) + ")";

            count++;
            l++;
        }

    } while (count < 20);   

    writeTopTen(decadeName, decade);
}

private static void writeAnomaliesToFile(Name[] list){
    System.out.println("Terminating... but first the anomalies in the data file:");

    checkAnomalies(list);

    System.out.println("Anomalies written to anomalies.txt.");
}

private static String nameEntry(){
    String nameInput = "";

    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");

    nameInput = keyboard.nextLine();

    return nameInput;

}

private static int checkListArray(String nameInput, Name[] list){
    int nameLocation = -1;
    int listLength = list.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++){
        if (nameInput.equalsIgnoreCase(list[i].getName())){
            validName = true;
            return nameLocation = i;
        }
    }

    if (nameLocation == -1){
        validName = false;
        return nameLocation;
    }
    return nameLocation;
}

private static void decadeMenu(){
    System.out.println("Enter number correpsonding to your decade:");
    System.out.println("   1 - 1900-1909");
    System.out.println("   2 - 1910-1919");
    System.out.println("   3 - 1920-1929");
    System.out.println("   4 - 1930-1939");
    System.out.println("   5 - 1940-1949");
    System.out.println("   6 - 1950-1959");
    System.out.println("   7 - 1960-1969");
    System.out.println("   8 - 1970-1979");
    System.out.println("   9 - 1980-1989");
    System.out.println("   10 - 1990-1999");
    System.out.println("   11 - 2000-2005");
}

private static int decadeSelection(){
    String decadeChoice;
    int decade;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a decade: ");
        decadeChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

        decade = checkDecade(decadeChoice);

    } while (!validDecade);

    return decade;
}

private static int checkDecade(String decadeChoice){
    int decade = 0;

    try {
        decade = Integer.parseInt(decadeChoice);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("That is not an integer. Please try again.");

        validDecade = false;
        return decade;
    }

    if (decade < 1 || decade > 11){
        System.out.println("Enter an integer between 1 and 11");

        validDecade = false;
        return decade;
    }
    else {
        validDecade = true;

        decade = changeDecade(decade);

        return decade;
    }
}

private static int changeDecade(int decade){
    int newDecade = 0;

    switch (decade){
        case 1:
            newDecade = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            newDecade = 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            newDecade = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            newDecade = 3;
            break;
        case 5:
            newDecade = 4;
            break;
        case 6:
            newDecade = 5;
            break;
        case 7:
            newDecade = 6;
            break;
        case 8:
            newDecade = 7;
            break;
        case 9:
            newDecade = 8;
            break;
        case 10:
            newDecade = 9;
            break;
        case 11:
            newDecade = 10;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return newDecade;
}

private static int getIndexOfSmallest(int decade, int startIndex, Name[] temp){
    int min = temp[startIndex].getPop(decade);
    int indexOfMin = startIndex;

    for (int index = startIndex + 1; index < temp.length; index++){
        if (temp[index].getPop(decade) < min){
            min = temp[index].getPop(decade);
            indexOfMin = index;
        }
    }

    return indexOfMin;
}

private static void interchange(int decade, int i, int j, Name[] temp){
    Name tempInt = temp[i];
    temp[i] = temp[j];
    temp[j] = tempInt;
}

private static String decadeYears(int decade){      
    String decadeYear = "";

    switch (decade){
        case 0:
            decadeYear = "1900 - 1909";
            break;
        case 1:
            decadeYear = "1910 - 1919";
            break;
        case 2:
            decadeYear = "1920 - 1929";
            break;
        case 3:
            decadeYear = "1930 - 1939";
            break;
        case 4:
            decadeYear = "1940 - 1949";
            break;
        case 5:
            decadeYear = "1950 - 1959";
            break;
        case 6:
            decadeYear = "1960 - 1969";
            break;
        case 7:
            decadeYear = "1970 - 1979";
            break;
        case 8:
            decadeYear = "1980 - 1989";
            break;
        case 9:
            decadeYear = "1990 - 1999";
            break;
        case 10:
            decadeYear = "2000 - 2005";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return decadeYear;
}

private static void writeTopTen(String[] decadeName, int decade){
    String years;

    years = decadeYears(decade);

    System.out.println("Ten most popular names (male and female) during the decade " + years + " were:");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i += 2){
        System.out.printf("%20s\t%20s\n", decadeName[i],decadeName[i + 1]);
    }
}

private static void checkAnomalies(Name[] list){
    Name[] temp = new Name[list.length];
    int anomalyCount = 0;
    int popTwo = 0;
    int popOne = 0;
    String[] anomalies = new String[list.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        temp[i] = list[i];
    }

    for (int decade = 0; decade < 11; decade++){

        for (int index = 0; index < temp.length; index++){
            int smallestIndex = getIndexOfSmallest(decade, index, temp);
            interchange(decade, index, smallestIndex, temp);
        }

        int rank = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < temp.length - 1; i += 2){

            popOne = temp[i].getPop(decade);
            popTwo = temp[i+1].getPop(decade);

            if (popOne != 0){
                rank++;
            }

            if (popOne  == rank && popTwo != rank){
                String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
                anomalies[anomalyCount] = "One name (" + temp[i].getName() + ") for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i].getPop(decade) + ".";
                anomalyCount++;
            }
            else if (popOne != rank && popTwo == rank){
                String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
                anomalies[anomalyCount] = "One name (" + temp[i+1].getName() + ") for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i+1].getPop(decade) + ".";
                anomalyCount++;
            }
            else if (popOne != rank && popTwo != rank){
                String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
                anomalies[anomalyCount] = "No names for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i].getPop(decade) + ".";
                anomalyCount++;
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the information provided by my professor:

There are 1,065 anomalies: in some cases, only one name with a particular rank in a decade or in other cases, no names in a decade with a particular rank. With 11 decades and 999 ranks to check, 1065 is only about 9.7% of the name-pairs that are broken or anomalous. There should be a pair of names for each rank (999) in each decade (11): this gives 10,989 name-pairs. Your code to do this will need to check each name in each decade for each rank in order to find all 1065 anomalies.

When I was debugging my program I saw that the ranks end on odd numbers. which is why I started my loop in checkAnomalies at 1 instead of 0 (considering that at 0 the names rank will be 0 and that is considered to be a name that was picked 1000 or less). When I run the program with:

```
String[] anomalies = new String[1065];
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1065
at NameApp.checkAnomalies(NameApp.java:512)
at NameApp.writeAnomaliesToFile(NameApp.java:259)
at NameApp.main(NameApp.java:43)
```

and when I change my code to be:

```
String[] anomalies = new String[temp.length];
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4429
at NameApp.checkAnomalies(NameApp.java:502)
at NameApp.writeAnomaliesToFile(NameApp.java:259)
at NameApp.main(NameApp.java:43)
```

I figure my error is in my loops but I can't figure out where.. I figured my loops are finding way more errors then their really is.. Just wondering if anyone can help me out with this.. It is really the only part that I need left. Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

This is the relevant code for what I need help with:

```
private static void writeAnomaliesToFile(Name[] list){
System.out.println("Terminating... but first the anomalies in the data file:");

checkAnomalies(list);

System.out.println("Anomalies written to anomalies.txt.");
}
```

method that is called:

```
private static void checkAnomalies(Name[] list){
Name[] temp = new Name[list.length];
int anomalyCount = 0;
int popTwo = 0;
int popOne = 0;
String[] anomalies = new String[list.length];

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    temp[i] = list[i];
}

for (int decade = 0; decade < 11; decade++){

    for (int index = 0; index < temp.length; index++){
        int smallestIndex = getIndexOfSmallest(decade, index, temp);
        interchange(decade, index, smallestIndex, temp);
    }

    int rank = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < temp.length - 1; i += 2){

        popOne = temp[i].getPop(decade);
        popTwo = temp[i+1].getPop(decade);

        if (popOne != 0){
            rank++;
        }

        if (popOne  == rank && popTwo != rank){
            String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
            anomalies[anomalyCount] = "One name (" + temp[i].getName() + ") for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i].getPop(decade) + ".";
            anomalyCount++;
        }
        else if (popOne != rank && popTwo == rank){
            String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
            anomalies[anomalyCount] = "One name (" + temp[i+1].getName() + ") for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i+1].getPop(decade) + ".";
            anomalyCount++;
        }
        else if (popOne != rank && popTwo != rank){
            String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
            anomalies[anomalyCount] = "No names for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i].getPop(decade) + ".";
            anomalyCount++;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: On the first one the entire size of the array is 1065, which means you can't actually access index 1065 as it's zero based. You should possibly narrow down this code so we can look at the important parts. The menu text, and anything else directly unrelated, can be removed.

Comment: I have made edits to the original put a place in there for the relevant code and also the "This is what the file looks like" is an actual link to view the names.txt

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself just had to sleep on it:

```
    private static void checkAnomalies(Name[] list) 
        throws FileNotFoundException{
    Name[] temp = new Name[list.length];
    String[] anomalies = new String[1065];
    int anomalyCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        temp[i] = list[i];
    }

    for (int decade = 0; decade < 11; decade++){
        for (int ranks = 1; ranks < 1000; ranks++){
            int found = 0;
            String tempName = "";

            String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                if (temp[i].getPop(decade) == ranks){
                    found++;
                }

                if (found == 1 && 
                        temp[i].getPop(decade) == ranks){
                    tempName = temp[i].getName();
                }
            }

            if (found == 0){
                anomalies[anomalyCount] = "No names "
                        + "for " + decadeYear + ", rank " 
                        + ranks + ".";
                anomalyCount++;
            }
            else if (found == 1){
                anomalies[anomalyCount] = "One "
                        + "Name (" + tempName + ") for " 
                        + decadeYear + ", rank " 
                        + ranks + ".";
                anomalyCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    writeAnomaliesFile(anomalies);
}

/*
 * Helper method: this method will create and write 
 * each anomalies to a text document called 
 * anomalies.txt. 
 */
private static void 
            writeAnomaliesFile(String[] anomalies) 
            throws FileNotFoundException{
    String fileName = "anomolies.txt";
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);

    for (int i = 0; i < anomalies.length; i++){
        outputStream.println(anomalies[i]);
    }

    outputStream.close();
}
```